# Pytest doesn't recognize -n option after pytest-xdist installation

Tags: python, pytest, xdist, pytest-xdist

I have installed pytest-xdist on top of a working pytest environment :

```
pip install pytest-xdist
```

and I have received this output

```
Downloading/unpacking pytest-xdist
  Downloading pytest-xdist-1.10.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pytest-xdist

    no previously-included directories found matching '.hg'
Downloading/unpacking execnet>=1.1 (from pytest-xdist)
  Downloading execnet-1.2.0.tar.gz (163kB): 163kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package execnet

    warning: no files found matching 'conftest.py'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytest>=2.4.2 in /Users/sal/Documents/code/Python/VirtualEnv/Spring/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pytest-xdist)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): py>=1.4.20 in /Users/sal/Documents/code/Python/VirtualEnv/Spring/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pytest>=2.4.2->pytest-xdist)
Installing collected packages: pytest-xdist, execnet
  Running setup.py install for pytest-xdist

    no previously-included directories found matching '.hg'
  Running setup.py install for execnet

    warning: no files found matching 'conftest.py'
Successfully installed pytest-xdist execnet
Cleaning up...
```

at this point I have tried to run my test suite in parallel

```
py.test -n 4
```

but I received this output instead

```
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: -n
```

Output of 'py.test --version is'

```
This is pytest version 2.6.2, imported from /Users/sal/Documents/code/Python/VirtualEnv/Spring/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest.pyc
setuptools registered plugins:
  pytest-capturelog-0.7 at /Users/sal/Documents/code/Python/VirtualEnv/Spring/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_capturelog.pyc
  pytest-contextfixture-0.1.1 at /Users/sal/Documents/code/Python/VirtualEnv/Spring/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_contextfixture.pyc
  pytest-cov-1.7.0 at /Users/sal/Documents/code/Python/VirtualEnv/Spring/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_cov.pyc
  pytest-django-2.6.2 at /Users/sal/Documents/code/Python/VirtualEnv/Spring/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.pyc
  pytest-pydev-0.1 at /Users/sal/Documents/code/Python/VirtualEnv/Spring/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_pydev.pyc
  pytest-runfailed-0.3 at /Users/sal/Documents/code/Python/VirtualEnv/Spring/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_runfailed.pyc
```

and pytest-xdist is effectively missing.

What I was wrong? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [py.test -n <number of processes> => "py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: -n"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24198753/py-test-n-number-of-processes-py-test-error-unrecognized-arguments-n)

Answer (score 6):

Like [user2412166](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2412166/user2412166), I suffered the same issue. Unlike user2412166, the solution in my case was to relax the permissions on the `xdist` and `pytest_xdist-1.14.dist-info` system directories installed by `pip3`.

Some backstory: For security, I run a strict `umask` on my system prohibiting *all* access to `other` users and write access to `group` users by default:

```
$ umask
027
```

While this is usually a good thing, it also occasionally gets me into trouble. Installing `python-xdist` via `pip3` under this `umask`:

```
$ sudo pip3 install pytest-xdist
```

...resulted in `pip3` prohibiting read and execution access to non-superusers – which had better be *only me*:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/xdist
drwxr-x---   3 root root 4.0K 2016-04-10 01:19 xdist/
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pytest_xdist-1.14.dist-info
drwxr-x---   3 root root 4.0K 2016-04-10 01:19 xdist/
```

While `pip3` was not wrong in doing so, `py.test` was (...*arguably!*) wrong in silently ignoring rather than explicitly reporting an obvious permissions issue during plugin detection.

This was trivially fixable by recursively granting `other` users both read and directory execution permissions for the afflicted system directories:

```
$ chmod -R o+rX /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/xdist
$ chmod -R o+rX /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pytest_xdist-1.14.dist-info
```

The proof is the command-line pudding:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/xdist
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K 2016-04-10 01:19 xdist/
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pytest_xdist-1.14.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K 2016-04-10 01:19 xdist/
$ py.test --version
This is pytest version 2.8.7, imported from /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/pytest.py
setuptools registered plugins:
  pytest-xdist-1.14 at /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/xdist/looponfail.py
  pytest-xdist-1.14 at /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/xdist/plugin.py
  pytest-xdist-1.14 at /usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/xdist/boxed.py
```

Thus was the unclear made clear, the buggy debugged, and the slow tests parallelized quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The problem is not with the version. Somehow py.test cannot see where xdist is. Here's what worked for me:

pip install pytest --user
pip install pytest-xdist --user

export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

Please try `py.test --version` and look at the output which explains where things are imported from, including plugins.  Very likely are not running the `py.test` that you think you are running.

Comment: I've added 'py.test --version' output to my question.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the environment you are installing and running things from.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and figured out it was because of a really old `setuptools` (the default version that ships on Centos6.7)

```
pip list | grep setuptools
setuptools (0.6rc11)
```

So first upgrade `setuptools`

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then reinstall `pytest` and `pytest-xdist`

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pytest pytest-xdist --force-reinstall
```

After this `pytest` was able to discover the `xdist` plugin.